# How to turn a series of strings from a pandas column into integers

Tags: python, pandas, split, int

I have a pandas data frame with a column on dates in this format "2016-05-03" These are strings btw. I need to convert them to an int from string and split at the hyphen('-') and only extract for the year so [0].

This is what I have tried to turn the string into an integer:

```
tyc.startDate = tyc.startDate.astype(np.int64)
```

But it is returning and error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2015-06-01'

and this is what I've done for splitting:

```
tyc.startDate.str.split('-')[0]
```

and

```
tyc.startDate.str.split('-', [0])
```

but this isn't working either, it's splitting and returning a list of all the rows in the column in this form: 
['2015', '06', '01'] and I want to just split for the year!

I'm sure there is a simple way to just convert to int and split for ('-') at position 0 and then put that into the df as a new column, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your data contains `NaN`s or some not datetime values:

```
tyc = pd.DataFrame({'startDate':['2016-05-03','2017-05-03', np.nan],
                    'col':[1,2,3]})
print (tyc)
   col   startDate
0    1  2016-05-03
1    2  2017-05-03
2    3         NaN
```

Use `str[0]` for return first list value of each row first. But then there is problem - some `NaNs`, which cannot be converted to `int` (be design) - so output is floats:

```
print (tyc.startDate.str.split('-').str[0].astype(float))
0    2016.0
1    2017.0
2       NaN
Name: startDate, dtype: float64
```

Another solution is convert to datetime by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and parse year by [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
print (pd.to_datetime(tyc.startDate, errors='coerce'))
0   2016-05-03
1   2017-05-03
2          NaT
Name: startDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (pd.to_datetime(tyc.startDate, errors='coerce').dt.year)
0    2016.0
1    2017.0
2       NaN
Name: startDate, dtype: float64
```

---

Solutions for remove `NaN`s:

```
tyc['year'] = pd.to_datetime(tyc.startDate, errors='coerce').dt.year
print (tyc)
   col   startDate    year
0    1  2016-05-03  2016.0
1    2  2017-05-03  2017.0
2    3         NaN     NaN
```

**1.**

Remove all rows with `NaN`s by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and then cast to int:

```
tyc = tyc.dropna(subset=['year'])
tyc['year'] = tyc['year'].astype(int)
print (tyc)
   col   startDate  year
0    1  2016-05-03  2016
1    2  2017-05-03  2017
```

**2.**

Replace `NaN`s by some int value like `1` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and then cast to `int`:

```
tyc['year'] = tyc['year'].fillna(1).astype(int)
print (tyc)
   col   startDate  year
0    1  2016-05-03  2016
1    2  2017-05-03  2017
2    3         NaN     1
```

Comment: Hmm, you write in comments some problem with another solution, so another solution work nice, so accepted? Or not?

Comment: There is problem only one solution can be accepted - so you have to choose between my or anothr solution. Is impossible accept both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
def mod_strings(date_str):
    try:
        return int(date_str.split('-')[0])
    except (AttributeError, IndexError):  # in case value is not as 
                                          # expected returning original value
        return date_str

tyc.startDate = tyc.startDate.apply(mod_strings)
```

but it might be easier to simply convert the whole column from strings to date objects and then use `tyc.startDate = tyc.startDate.dt.year` (assuming pandas version >= 0.16)

Comment: Hey @DeepSpace! Thanks for this. I have tried it but I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @s.23 Obviously some of the rows contain a float object and not a string in `startDate` column. You need to be sure about what data types you are working with.

Comment: So is then i should use an exception?

Comment: @s.23 I don't know, it's your code. You can use an exception or make sure all rows have valid data.

Comment: I see, thank you. 1- how would that exception look like?. 2- You mentioned converting the string to date objects will this help with the float issue also?

Comment: @s.23 `You mentioned converting the string to date objects will this help with the float issue also?` No, you can't convert a float to a date object.

Comment: Thanks, that was a lot of help! It has left decimals however and therefore, rendered all as floats. [2015.0]  can i remove this with (replace( ' . ' ,  '  ')?